# SQL Server function returns unrecognized text

Tags: sql-server, udf

I have created a user defined function that strips input text from HTML tags, but found that it also destroys Arabic text for some reason.

I thought: maybe the function's logic causes the text to be converted to VARCHAR somewhere, so I made the function very simple.. It takes an NVARCHAR and returns it to the caller.. Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_test] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
begin
  return @string
end
```

then I made a small test:

```
select dbo.udf_test('إختبار اللغة العربية Testing Arabic ');
```

the output is:

```
?????? ????? ??????? Testing Arabic
```

The output is fine if I do this:

```
select 'إختبار اللغة العربية Testing Arabic ';
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: Try `N'...'` and see how you go

Comment: @ta.speot.is where do i use `N'...'` in the function or on the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the string a NVARCHAR type. Adding an N before the string should solve the problem

```
select dbo.udf_test(N'إختبار اللغة العربية Testing Arabic ');
```